# How to the Find the current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment Home = fm.findFragmentByTag("Home");
Fragment rec = fm.findFragmentByTag("Recents");
Fragment search = fm.findFragmentByTag("Search");
```

I am trying to get the current fragmenTag like this, i am checking whether its loaded or not. The condition inside does not execute at all. Am i doing the right way.

```
if(Home != null){
   // Do the following
}
```

Comment: How are you adding the fragments?

Comment: When are you doing this check? Are you sure you're checking after you've added the fragments?

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your current fragment is visible or not by following:

```
if (Home.isVisible()) {
   // write your "home" fragment code here
}
```

Comment: I believe that would just cause a null reference exception. He's saying that Home == null.